# Recommend an Outlook replacement

Tags: software-recommendation, email-client

Not a fan of Evolution or Thunderbird.

Is there a decent alternative to Outlook on Ubuntu?

Comment: What are your requirements?  Do you need particular functionality, and are there particular thinks you don't like about Thunderbird and Evolution?

Comment: If you are not a fan of thunderbird, but want a desktop mail app, try pine. my favourite, after thunderbird.

Comment: Is this a matter of opinion/taste or functionality ? First you said "*Not a fan...*" then, "*is there a decent alternative?*" , of course there is and its name is Thunderbird. If you don't like it I cannot help.

Comment: @NikTh How can thunderbird be an alternative to itself? Your comment doesn't make a single bit of sense to me. Can you please elaborate? If you only had to say "I cannot help" then you didn't have to say it, you could just have avoided commenting which would exhibit that you couldn't help.
I'm also looking for an alternative to thunderbird, more looking and functioning like outlook. Missing functionality? How about starting from "It doesn't have a friggin' text highlight functionality **built into it**"

Comment: Prospect- mail might be good choice.  See my answer here. https://askubuntu.com/a/1275365/39340

Answer (score 2):

I like [Zimbra Desktop](http://www.zimbra.com/downloads/ne-downloads.html)  hope you do like it :)

it supports Yahoo! Mail, Gmail, Microsoft Live Hotmail, AOL Mail, Microsoft Exchange IMAP, IMAP, and POP

Comment: I've also used Zimbra.  I'm not a big fan, but it works.  Like most of the solutions mentioned here, it seems a bit bloated.  But for compatibility and features it would be in the top three for me.

Comment: It is slow and bloated. I started using it and liked the features, but it was so bloated and slow that I gave up.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/features/#popular) - I'm a huge fan of Opera's integrated Email, Chat. It's much more than a browser, it even has extensions now!

Comment: I was as well, although Opera has functionality of syncing contacts, which is a major pain.  I'd love to sync with my google contacts, as I have everything up on my phone.

Comment: I'm hoping that extension developers will start to see Opera as a great opportunity to extend Opera for those extra options that are missing - just like contacts sync to google or bookmark syncing to Xmarks, we'll have to wait and see.

Answer (score 1):

Kmail(requires kde libraries and qt4...obviosly)
Claws(GTK)
Sylpheed(GTK)
Balsa(GTK)
Personally I'm a die hard Thunderbird fan for Gnome and Kmail for KDE

Comment: AFAIK Thunderbird doesn't have Exchange support. So cannot completely replace Evolution for people using Microsoft Exchange.

Comment: Yeah I know,but I never used microsoft exchange and Evolution doesn't closes to messaging menu,one have to use alltray or stuff like that. Not that thunderbird does ,it needs extension for minimizng to the upper panel applets,but I kinda prefer extensions to alltray.

Comment: I don't find a single GUI mail client on Linux that fits the bill. I find mutt to be awesome, but it is not usable by most

Comment: Thunderbird can be used to connect to exchange server by using IMAP. I use it to connect to my office network and never had problems.

Comment: I am talking about full Exchange integration. I don't think any mail client still has that

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going with `Thunderbird`. Install one from the repository

It does not have Exchange support. If you workplace/institution uses Microsoft Exchange, then you might find it a problem.

The one in repository is [`Thunderbird 3.1.7`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/thunderbird) which is really good. It might be sluggish due to some XULRunner issues, but it doesn't crawl when you have to download 3000 mails at once. I have configured it with all my 4 email ids and it works perfectly.

If you are adding a Gmail account, then it is just a few clicks away. Adding a Gmail account is probably the simplest on Thunderbird of all the email providers.

Comment: I think he was looking for a solution that wasn't Thunderbird (or Evolution).

Comment: The questions says no Thunderbird, no Evolution.

Comment: I use Davmail to connect to Exchange and Thunderbird then connects through Davmail.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar conundrum a while back, and after weighing out all options decided to move to Google Apps/Gmail with no regrets. Gmail is an able aggregator of multiple accounts, works across browsers and OS well, and gets you away from a single machine as your email hub.

Comment: That's not an email desktop client...

Comment: Fully agree with your statement. Yet, I suggest to have a copy of Gmail e-mails on standalone PC.

Answer (score 1):

[claws-mail](http://www.claws-mail.org)

[Here](http://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Connecting_to_MS_Exchange) is how you use it with MS exchange

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird with lightning and this groupware http://www.sogo.nu/english.html
You can have a good outlook + exchange replacement

Answer (score 0):

If Gmail is an acceptable alternative, the GNOME Gmail package integrates the web interface into GNOME.