# Microsoft Outlook 2010 Ubuntu similar app

Tags: email-client

Please recommend me a similar app. Thunderbird is almoust ok but it cannot search within attachments. Search on Thunderbird doesn't work within attachments: doc, pdf, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email App On Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554811/email-app-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/554811/email-app-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Hiri claims to be a complete alternative for MS Outlook, but its 14 day trial and then paid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommend an Outlook replacement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24083/recommend-an-outlook-replacement)

Comment: Geary doesn't search inside attachments and GNOME Gmail package its a web interface not a desktop email app.