# Alternative to Microsoft Outlook

Tags: software-recommendation, email, calendar

I recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows 10. I used to rely heavily on MS Outlook, and still do, and I want something similar in Ubuntu.

I need an alternative that provides/supports/integrates (not sure what the appropriate word is) email, contacts and calendars. Tasklist also would be ideal but is not necessary.

I've been using Mailspring and KOrganizer, and while they're brilliant individually, I want something that combines everything under one roof.

Thoughts?

Comment: There is something recent called [Prospect Mail](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-prospect-mail-unofficial-outlook-365-client-on-ubuntu-18-04). Check it out

Comment: you can set up thunderbird

Answer (score 8):

Did you try **Prospect Mail** ?

This has been considered as Unofficial Outlook 365 Client on Ubuntu.  See more details here: https://snapcraft.io/prospect-mail

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

then

```
sudo snap install prospect-mail
```

Comment: after using thunderbird for a week or so i took a look at prospect mail. it seems like its just a thin client on the outlook web UI. its perfect, fast and easy, dark mode, everything works. you can tell its not a standalone app but if you have a good connection its barely noticeable. once I looked at resource monitor and saw 5 GB of memory free up after i closed thunderbird my mind was made up.

Comment: This sounded nice to me, but it seems like it's not maintained for the last 4 months or so, issues piling up.

Comment: Prospect Mail is maintained. (I'm the creator ) I try to review issues/PRs and improve CI/CD from time to time.

Comment: Works as needed, thanks for this !!

Comment: not really an alternative. it's just a browser that opens web version of outlook.

Comment: @julian-alarcon And now, 1.5 years later, your last commit to the repo was made on the exact day of this comment :D I guess nowadays you don't maintain anymore, right?

Comment: New version available now, 0.5.0

Answer (score 7):

Thunderbird with the lightning extension provides a single application for managing emails, calendars and tasks:

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird xul-ext-lightning
```

You can then install more add-ons, for instance:

- Provider for Google Calendar : to sync with your google calendar.
- Exchange calendar : to sync with MS outlook servers ([this version](https://github.com/ExchangeCalendar/exchangecalendar/releases) is working fine).

Answer (score 5):

You may have a look at the **[Evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_(software))** Ubuntu featured mail client, with calendar, tasks, contacts and so.
- Have the look and feel of Outlook
- It can import your Outlook PST data file
- Can also connect to Ms Exchange server

Install from Software-Center or from command line

```
apt-get install -y evolution
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please also add some links to setup Evolution with microsoft account?

Comment: I found [this blog](https://rc.partners.org/kb/article/2702) useful.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE October 2022**

It might seem that Basic authentication is still available, but Microsoft deprecated this officially. All of sudden my Evolution Mail stopped working, and that's the reason. You are now forced to use OAuth.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

Answer (score 0):

Outlook has been released as PWA. It works perfectly for me.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-web-version-of-outlook-like-a-desktop-app-b360bd9a-00dc-43a4-bdf8-71cdeeb78e83