# Hotmail calendar not being added in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: email, thunderbird, evolution, calendar

When I add my accounts in the "Connect your data in the cloud" section, I usually get the mail, calendar, contacts, etc options for my gmail and exchange accounts. But when I go add my hotmail account I only get the option to add my mail and contact, and nothing else.

I would like to add my calendar, because that's where most of my calendar stuff is, but I don't know what to do.

If it makes a difference, I use Evolution as my email/calendar client but thinking of switching to Thunderbird/Lightning Calendar.

Comment: May I suggest you visit https://askubuntu.com/a/1047804/197910 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to Microsoft Outlook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047803/alternative-to-microsoft-outlook)